# How to determine $\lambda_i$ when given those equations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, analysis

Suppose that
$\int_{-\infty }^\infty x^ic_0 \exp(\Sigma_{k=1}^4\lambda_kx^k)dx=e_i$
how to determine each $\lambda_i$

also we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_0 \exp(\Sigma_{k=1}^4\lambda_kx^k)dx=1$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? Can you solve such a problem in a simpler version, e.g. if there are only one or two $\lambda_k$? Have you perhaps seen a similar problem already?

Comment: Thank you . Yeah I can solve it for  two $\lambda_i$ because I can make use of the Gaussian distribution but I have no idea about 3 or more $\lambda$'s